# Get @value and replace it with a regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get every username ( @name ) out of a text and replace it with the same value as it had before but in a link. I've already got the following code and it's working but if i have multiple @ tags in a text, it will replace each of them with the last. So e.g:

@twitter @google @facebook will be @facebook @ facebook @facebook

```
for (var i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; ++i) {
        var item = cusid_ele[i];  
        const str = item.innerHTML;
        const regex = /([@])\w+/g;
        var arr = [];

        let m;

        while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
            // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
            if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
                regex.lastIndex++;
            }

            // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
            m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
                if(match != "@"){

                    arr.push(match)
                }
            });

        }
        for(k=0;k!=arr.length;k++){
            spl = arr[k].split("@")
            item.innerHTML = str.replace(regex, `<a href="`+spl[1]+`" target="_blank" class="at">`+arr[k]+`</a>`);    
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy approach using regex:

```js
var text = "@one @two @three test";
var matches = text.match(/@\w+/g);
var result = text.replace(/@\w+/g, matches[matches.length-1]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: If I run this code i got the same "error" that thee last word replaces the first ones :(

Comment: @Eyk Not sure what you mean, could you check the answer again (I've edited it)

Comment: My problem is that I want to get one two three test instead of three three three :D @nicael

Answer (score 0):

Solved with jQuery:

```
      $('.postContent').each(function(){ // to each <p>
          r = /@\w+/g; // big letter with word symbols, global search
          function f(x){
            return '<a href="'+x+'" class="at">'+x+'</a>' // rewrited
          }
          h = $(this).html(); //get
          h = h.replace(r,f); //replace
          $(this).html(h); //set
        }) //done   
     }
```